# How to reset data in block after click?

Tags: angular, rxjs

When user clicks "Load new data click" it displays data in template. How to clear old data after next click until data coming?
Also after click the button "Open card click" is disapered.

I tried in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-rgiklz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-rgiklz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me, you have made too much complicated code for simple things.
Fix for your case just will add more complication.
I would recommend you to rework all that code.

Now about the issue itself. The solution is to have a separate variable or hot observable (subject). for example `isLoading: boolean` or `isLoading$: BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)`. As for me in this case, just a variable is enough. The main point is that you need to have the ability to control it from the outside. You can not do that with the regular Observable.
Then at the start of your `load` function, you just change this value to true. And after your observable(s) is/are finalized you can make it false.`finalize` pipe from `RxJS` is nice for that.  Then you can control the visibility of template parts depending on this value.

Also, I would advise you to merge your observables at `TS` level instead of HTML. As for me, it is much more readable and you will keep the template cleaner. I even would keep your `state` entries in different class variables. Consider using `combineLatest`, `forkJoin` etc, to get the results of your observables at once. The right pipe choice depends on your real code.

Comment: I have tried this. When use click I get load$ subject, then I try to load image and fields, then get result stream. But i dont get data in console:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-rxjs-rgiklz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html